# RTMP edge server?

Tags: rtmp

I need a simple RTMP proxy, which listen for an incomming live RTMP stream (from Wirecast), and relay that to end users. I don't need any re-transcoding.
I fail to find any suitable software after googling and testing for hours, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried nginx + rtmp module (https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) ?

Answer (score 1):

Set up the [nginx rtmp module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) on a server and configure the [push](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#push) option to go to the destination you want.

Example config:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;

            #pushes the stream without transcoding to a set destination
            push rtmp://some.domain.name:1935/foo/bar
        }
    }
}
```